# Logstash date match not update @timestamp

Tags: date, format, logstash

Log string example:

```
2014-06-01  00:00:48    192.168.1.1 968 http://yandex.ru
```

Logstash config:

```
input {
    file {
    path => "/home/michael/logs/squid.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{YEAR:year}-%{MONTHNUM:month}-%{MONTHDAY:day}\t+%{TIME:time}\t+%{IPORHOST:userID}|{WORD:userID}\t+%{NUMBER:response_size}\t+%{URIHOST:dst_host}|{URI:dst_host}" ]
  }
  mutate {
    add_field => { "timestamp" => "%{year}-%{month}-%{day} %{time}" } 
  }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
  }
}

output {
    elasticsearch { host => localhost }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

While not adding date filter it works perfectly: log parses and field adds. But with date filter  some parts of messages disappears, logstash logs says:

```
{:timestamp=>"2014-07-26T22:48:44.413000+0600", :message=>"Failed parsing date from field", :field=>"timestamp", :value=>"%{year}-%{month}-%{day} %{time}", :exception=>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "%{year}-%{month}-%{day} %{time}", :level=>:warn}
```

What's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your configuration and log, it  works on me with version 1.4.1!

I think it is probably your grok pattern parsing error, otherwise it will not occur this error message `:value=>"%{year}-%{month}-%{day} %{time}"`.

The error message means the content of `timestamp` field your add is `%{year}-%{month}-%{day} %{time}`. 
which means the grok filter parsing error.

What you can do is, check your log whether the log is `whitespace (" ")` or `tab (\t)`. If it is whitespace, you cannot use `\t` in  the pattern.

**Updated:**

You can change the `\t` to `[ \t]`. This patterns parse the whitespace and `\t`.

```
%{YEAR:year}-%{MONTHNUM:month}-%{MONTHDAY:day}[ \t]+%{TIME:time}[ \t]+%{IPORHOST:userID}|{WORD:userID}[ \t]+%{NUMBER:response_size}[ \t]+%{URIHOST:dst_host}|{URI:dst_host}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: I checked - tabs are here. And I can't understand, why grok parses well without date filter and fails with that. My logstash version is 1.4.2, if it matters.

Comment: When I tested with your config, I meet the "_grokparsefailure" error. Please check when the date parse error occur, the grok failure tag occur or not. I think it is no matter what version you use. From the error message you post, the grok parse failure and cause the timestamp value is %{year}-%{month}-%{day} %{time}

Comment: I removed all indexes and try to restart logstash service twice. The result - is two different (seems to be random) corrupted messages (`rt.ru/www/delivery/lg.php?` and `:36 192.168.1.1 464 http://mc.yandex.ru/clmap/13086418?`) with `%{year}-%{month}-%{day} %{time}` in timestamp field and `_grokparsefailure` tags.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please refer to the grok pattern. It worked on me.

Comment: Thanks. You are right: it was the grok issue. I finished with `%{YEAR:year}-%{MONTHNUM:month}-%{MONTHDAY:day}%{SPACE}%{TIME:time}%{SPACE}(%{IPORHOST:userID}|%{WORD:userID})%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:response_size}%{SPACE}(%{URI:dst_host}|%{URIHOST:dst_host})` filter.